# TDAmeritrade Quote Summary TREE vs APRN

Tags: stocks, quotes

Why does TDAmeritrade's Quote Summary tab, display the Shares outstanding differently for TREE vs APRN?

On TDAmeritrade, when I search on the ticker APRN for Blue Apron Holdings, the Quote Summary screen shows 30M shares outstanding; however if I navigate to the Fundamentals tab it shows a float of 30M, and Shares Outstanding displays 190.1M.

When I search for TREE, the quote summary shows 12M shares outstanding; when I navigate to the Fundamentals tab it shows 12M shares outstanding, and 7.1M for float.

Why does the quote summary value for shares outstanding match the values on the fundamentals tab for TREE but not for APRN?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is related to the fact that Blue Apron completed its IPO very recently and insider shares are likely still under a lockup period.  So in the case of APRN stock only the 30mm shares involved in the IPO are trading until the insider lockup expires which is usually about 90 days.